# Making a copy of a string recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I'm learning recursion for my intro computer science class and I'm really struggling with applying it. If I have some method like this:

```
public static String buildString(String str) {
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

How would I go about making and returning a copy of the String in the prototype by recursively calling buildString without using an iterator? I've tried using substring a lot, but I kept getting stackoverflow errors.

Disclaimer: This is not a part of a homework assignment or anything of the sort. It's a hypothetical method that I came up with.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to accomplish with this specific case. This could be a case where recursion is being used for the wrong reason.

Comment: I'm trying to make a method that creates a copy of a String in the prototype (in this case str) by recursively calling buildString without using an iterator. I know there are easier ways to do that, but I want to know how to do this for the purpose of learning recursion.

Comment: That's the point, this is not a good use case for recursion. Why don't you try a more classic example like Fibonacci?

Comment: You say you've tried things, but you don't show what you've tried. If the method is to make a copy of the String (which is immutable), why couldn't it just return the string? Or `return str.substring(0, str.length());`? What would the point of recursion be, here? To copy the string one character at a time?

Comment: Yes, to copy the string one character at a time. I probably should have specified that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide exit condition: if input string is empty, return the empty string.
   Use methods `String::isEmpty` or `String::length`
2. Call `buildString` recursively using substring and adding a character to the result.  Here two implementations are possible: pick up the first or the last character and concatenate the character accordingly.
   Use methods `String::charAt` or `String::substring` (two versions).

As this seems to be a self-learning exercise, the code of the solution is not provided.

Please be aware that `StackOverflowError` is highly possible with the recursion if the input string is large enough.

Comment: One question: I wonder what would be the result of the above when using String::substring like this:      ...return (str.substring(0,in).clone() + buildString(str,in+1));

Comment: Why would you need `clone`?  Why would you need to pass `in + 1` argument which has not been mentioned in the OP's question?  Is this comment related to another answer by Turtle?

Comment: Yes, it's related to Turtle's answer. Clone()'s intend was to prevent (or maybe risking the opposite), a stack overflow

Comment: Not sure how `clone()` could prevent `StackOverflowError` if the string has the length of 100K order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use this.

```
public static String buildString(String str, int in) {
    if(in == str.length()) return "";
    return str.charAt(in) + buildString(str, in+1);
}
```

Pass `buildString(str, 0)` as your input.

Comment: `in` is not really needed